# Altering the subtitle(.srt) format, replace ',' with ' --> '

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file, replace, subtitle

I have a bunch of videos, where the subtitle file(.srt) had it as one below.

```
0:00:22.540,0:00:25.440
Hello this is a test
```

VLC interprets it wrong, and just shows the time 0:00:25.440 on screen.

So, I planned to replace all the `\d,\d` to `\d-->\d`

I could easily search for \d,\d, but how would I replace it to \d-->\d

```
Input   : 0:00:22.540,0:00:25.440
Output  : 0:00:22.540 --> 0:00:25.440
Expected
```

I tried this

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.srt) -replace '0,0', '0 --> 0'
```

But I used `0,0` to search and replace? How can I make it for all digits.

Can someone help on this. I am on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

- `(?<=\d)` Look behind. Checks if the `,` is presceded by a digit.
- `,` Matches `,`
- `(?=\d)` Look ahead. Checks if the `,` is followed by a digit.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rW8sH4/1)

**Code**

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.srt) -replace '(?<=\d),(?=\d)', ' --> '
```

---

You can also use capturing group to perform the same as

```
(\d),(\d)
```

Replace with

```
$1 -> $2
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rW8sH4/2)

**Code**

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.srt) -replace '(\d),(\d)', '$1 --> $2'
```

**Notepad++ Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Tamilana .. Nanben da :p

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Tamilan...not actually. I just work here, from a neighboring state :)